# is it possible to run the nnn File Manager on Windows?

Tags: file-management, compatibility, wsl2

edited:

using powershell I installed what I thought was `nnn` (https://github.com/jarun/nnn):

```
PS> python.exe -m pip install nnn
```

how do I run it? does it run on PowerShell or cmd?

---

update:

the `nnn` file manager is actually written in `C` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nnn_(file_manager)), so the above command installed something else.

Still I'd like to know if I can install and run the `nnn` file manager under MS Windows.

`WSL2` might be the way to go, WIP.

Update: nnn is up and runnign on a WSL2 linux. but it seems to be complex to enter the Windows file system from there. gotta figure that out now

Comment: You would have to run it within WSL2, how your it within WSL2, would be exactly how you would run it within Linux.

Comment: There is no reason that this wouldnt run under WSL1.. but @Anaksunaman answer below is even better!

Answer (score 1):

> Using PowerShell I successfully installed nnn (https://github.com/jarun/nnn) [with] `PS> python.exe -m pip install nnn`

Are you certain you installed the project you wish to use? Because [nnn from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/nnn/#files) (where `-m pip install nnn` would normally get files from) looks to be a completely different application.

Superficially, it seems to be some sort of number reversing utility with no clear links to the GitHub project you linked in your original question. Furthermore, the "nnn" project on GitHub doesn't even appear to based primarily on Python.

Comment: true. as of wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nnn_(file_manager)) the ```n``` file manager is written in ```C```. Thanx for pointing out my mistake. I still would like to know if I can run this file manager on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It was available under [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), but not installed by default. You could install it (or MC, and many other useful *nix tools) with

```
 pacman -S nnn
```

after setting up the MSYS2 environment.